# RIch Text box Requirement in WPF

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have a requirement in WPF in which...

1. I want Rich text box to be used as dateTemplate  for a listview for one particular column(which has remarks)
2. I have set of key word (add, search, location etc..)
   In that column I want all those keywords to be highlighted in yellow colour.
3. I have another TextBox .If I type any word for searching in that text box and it exists in listview then it should be highlighted with green.
4. If I search the keyword which are in yellow then they should not be highlighted with green they should be in yellow colour.
5. If I have “added” word in which add is highlighted in yellow then when I search for “added” “add” should be in yellow and “ed” should be in green.

Any help is appreciated. I have tried several ways but failed at the last point above.

//Code snippet

// Xaml File

```
<Window x:Class="RichtextBoxhighlight.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:src="clr-namespace:RichtextBoxhighlight"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="406" Width="855"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <src:ContentPlainConverter x:Key="typeConverter" />
        <src:TestConvertor x:Key="spaceRem"/>
        <Style x:Key="RichTextBoxWithRoundedCorners" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type FlowDocument}" TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocument}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Margin="114,14,130,255" Name="txtText" />
        <Grid>
            <ListView Height="241" ItemsSource="{Binding CollRemarks}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,126,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="827" >
                <ListView.View  >
                    <GridView >
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=type}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Operatorid}"  Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="CreatedEmployeeId" Content="Operator"/>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Width="710">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <src:BindableRichTextBox  Document ="{Binding Path=remarks, Converter= {StaticResource typeConverter}}" HighlightPhrase="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource spaceRem}}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="CommentText" Content="Remark" />
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>

                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


//BindableRichTextBox class :

namespace RichtextBoxhighlight
{
    public class BindableRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        public static string oldstring;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Document", typeof(FlowDocument),
            typeof(BindableRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            (null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDocumentChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightPhraseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightPhrase", typeof(string),
            typeof(BindableRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateHighlighting)));

        public string HighlightPhrase
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HighlightPhraseProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HighlightPhraseProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void UpdateHighlighting(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //invoked on text box search 
            ApplyHighlight(d as BindableRichTextBox);
            ApplyAllHighlight(d as BindableRichTextBox);
        }

        //  Gets or sets the Document of RichtextBox
        public new FlowDocument Document
        {
            get
            {
                return (FlowDocument)this.GetValue(DocumentProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(DocumentProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Method invoked on documnet formation.
        public static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {

                RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)obj;
               // ApplyHighlight(rtb as BindableRichTextBox);
                rtb.Document = (FlowDocument)args.NewValue;
                ApplyAllHighlight(rtb as BindableRichTextBox);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 

            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation logic for Text Changed search highlight
        /// </summary>

        private static void ApplyHighlight(BindableRichTextBox tb)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tb != null && tb.Document != null)
                {

                    string highlightPhrase = tb.HighlightPhrase;

                    // Frame the highlight word to skip them from getting highlighted by searchtext 

                    string highlightWords = "(";

                    for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Highlightwords.Count; i++)
                    {

                        highlightWords += MainWindow.Highlightwords[i];
                        if (i != MainWindow.Highlightwords.Count - 1)
                            highlightWords += "|";

                    }

                    highlightWords += ")";


                    var start = tb.Document.ContentStart;
                    TextRange range = new TextRange(start, tb.Document.ContentEnd);
                    range.ClearAllProperties();
                    Regex ignore = new Regex(highlightWords, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    string Text = range.Text;
                    int index_match = 0;


                    if (highlightPhrase != string.Empty && highlightPhrase != null)
                    {
                        while (start != null && start.CompareTo(tb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
                        {
                            // Comparison to skip the key words in the column to be highlighted
                            if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
                            {

                                index_match = Text.IndexOf(highlightPhrase, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                if (index_match >= 0)
                                {
                                    //Ignore all Keyword highlight by incrementing start and moving to next match
                                    MatchCollection matches = ignore.Matches(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
                                    if (matches != null)
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            if ((index_match >= matches[i].Index && index_match <= matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length))
                                            {
                                                start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                                                Text = new TextRange(start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), start.DocumentEnd).Text;
                                                //Highlight the search text if part before keyword
                                                if (highlightPhrase.Length > matches[i].Length)
                                                {
                                                var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(highlightPhrase.Length - matches[i].Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));
                                                    textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
                                                }
                                                if (start != null && start.CompareTo(tb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
                                                {
                                                    index_match = Text.IndexOf(highlightPhrase, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                                    if (index_match >= 0)
                                                    {
                                                        matches = ignore.Matches(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
                                                        if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
                                                            i--;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        break;
                                                }

                                            }
                                            else if ((highlightPhrase.Length - 1 >= matches[i].Index && highlightPhrase.Length + index_match <= matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length))
                                            {
                                                //Highlight the search text if part after keyword
                                                var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(index_match, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(matches[i].Index, LogicalDirection.Backward));
                                                textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
                                                start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                                                Text = new TextRange(start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), start.DocumentEnd).Text;
                                                if (start != null && start.CompareTo(tb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
                                                {
                                                    index_match = Text.IndexOf(highlightPhrase, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                                    if (index_match >= 0)
                                                    {
                                                        matches = ignore.Matches(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));
                                                        if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
                                                            i--;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (index_match >= 0 && start != null && (start.CompareTo(tb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0))
                                    {
                                        //Highlight the search text typed if not part of Keywords
                                        var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(index_match, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(index_match + highlightPhrase.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));
                                        textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
                                        start = textrange.End;
                                        Text = new TextRange(textrange.End, start.DocumentEnd).Text;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    break;

                            }
                            if (start != null && start.CompareTo(tb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
                                start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation logic for key words highlight
        /// </summary>
        private static void ApplyAllHighlight(BindableRichTextBox rtb)
        {
            try
            {
                if (rtb != null)
                {
                    string highlightWords = "(";

                    for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Highlightwords.Count; i++)
                    {

                        highlightWords += MainWindow.Highlightwords[i];
                        if (i != MainWindow.Highlightwords.Count - 1)
                            highlightWords += "|";

                    }

                    highlightWords += ")";

                    Regex reg = new Regex(highlightWords, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


                    var start = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
                    while (start != null && start.CompareTo(rtb.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
                    {
                        if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
                        {
                            var match = reg.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));

                            var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));
                            textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
                            start = textrange.End;
                        }
                        start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }


//Content of list view remarks column and keywords to be highlighted

//Key word to be highlighted
            Highlightwords = new List<string>();
            Highlightwords.Add("mment");
            Highlightwords.Add("ADD");
            Highlightwords.Add("LOCATION");
            Highlightwords.Add("arch");
       // Remarks in list view
            CollRemarks = new ObservableCollection<evcom>();
            string remar = "search for added comments in location added";
            CollRemarks.Add(new evcom { type = "Info", Operatorid = "1728", remarks = remar });
            remar = "searched for added add comments in location added LOCATIONS";
            CollRemarks.Add(new evcom { type = "Info", Operatorid = "1783", remarks = remar });
```

Comment: If everything is working but the last then post the code you have.

Comment: Only a comment but I would consider parsing out the words and then apply the highlight logic a word at a time.  Then you know if both hits are on the same word.  And markup the FlowDocument directly not the RTB.